# Sitecore LinkManager ExpandDynamicLinks does not resolve the site URL

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7

I am having a problem with the `ExpandDynamicLinks` in Sitecore.

I am using the following method passing `true` for `siteResolving`. The problem is the site is not being resolved as promissed.

```
bodyExpandedLinks = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks(email.Body.Value, true);
```

I did set in my provider to never resolve the site because that is what I want for the whole site except for this email body above.

```
 alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false"
```

Does anybody know how to force that?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one option might be to check if `AlwaysIncludeServerUrl` is set to False before your call to `ExpandDynamicLinks`. If it's False you can explicitly call `Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions.DefaultOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true` and then set it back to False after you have called `ExpandDynamicLinks`.

Comment: This property is ReadOnly :/
"Property or indexer 'Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Comment: Updated my answer. Not sure if this will work but might be worth a try

Comment: That works! And it is better then having a new linkManager configuration only to include the server url. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is tagged with sitecore7, but I would like to share a solution for Sitecore 8.1. I don't know if it works for 7 or not. It is adapted from `Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider.ExpandDynamicLinks()`:

```
var linkParser = new LinkProvider.LinkParser();
var urlOptions = LinkManager.Provider.GetDefaultUrlOptions(); // returns a clone.
urlOptions.SiteResolving = true;
urlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
text = linkParser.ExpandDynamicLinks(text, urlOptions);
```

This does not work for media links because `Sitecore.Links.DynamicLink.BuildMediaUrl()` and `Sitecore.Links.MediaLinkExpander.Expand()` completely ignore their UrlOptions parameter. If you need full media urls, wrap your code with this:

```
using (new SettingsSwitcher("Media.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl", "true"))
{
    phrase = linkParser.ExpandDynamicLinks(phrase, urlOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative method.

I did add a extra link provider, with the same configurations but the alwaysIncludeServerUrl which I set to true.

```
<add name="sitecore_expandlinks" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="true" (...) >
```

Then I got the provider using the API.

```
bodyExpandedLinks = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.Providers["sitecore_expandlinks"].ExpandDynamicLinks(email.Body.Value, true);
```

If someone else has a more cohesive option I would much appreciate

Thanks.